# how to fix UNMET DEPENDENCY errors on expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, serverside-javascript

I'm getting started with express JS and NodeJs
using the
[ExpressJSGuide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)

I'm stuck at the

> npm ls

part, it throws the following errors

└─┬ express@3.5.0
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY buffer-crc32 0.2.1

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY commander 1.3.2

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY connect 2.14.1

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY cookie 0.1.1

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY cookie-signature 1.0.3

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY debug >= 0.7.3 < 1

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY fresh 0.2.2

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY merge-descriptors 0.0.2

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY methods 0.1.0

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mkdirp 0.3.5

├── UNMET DEPENDENCY range-parser 1.0.0

└── UNMET DEPENDENCY send 0.2.0

npm ERR! missing: connect@2.14.1, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: commander@1.3.2, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: range-parser@1.0.0, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.3.5, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: cookie@0.1.1, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: buffer-crc32@0.2.1, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: fresh@0.2.2, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: methods@0.1.0, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: send@0.2.0, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: cookie-signature@1.0.3, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: merge-descriptors@0.0.2, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! missing: debug@>= 0.7.3 < 1, required by express@3.5.0

npm ERR! not ok code 0

does anyone know how to fix this?

Already tried

> npm install dependency-name

like

> npm install cookie-signature

but it only thrown the following errors

npm WARN package.json express@3.5.0 No README data

npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.3 No README data

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-1.0.3.tgz

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-1.0.3.tgz

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chown '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, chown '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json']

npm ERR!   errno: 50,

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   path: '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json',

npm ERR!   fstream_finish_call: 'chown',

npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',

npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json',

npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',

npm ERR!   fstream_stack:

npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19',

npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7',

npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "cookie-signature"

npm ERR! cwd /misc/htdocs/hello-world

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.6

npm ERR! path /misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json

npm ERR! fstream_path /misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json

npm ERR! fstream_type File

npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter

npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! errno 50

npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, chown '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie-signature/package.json'

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7

npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     /misc/htdocs/hello-world/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0

Answer (score 4):

You might try to run `npm cache clean`. I had similar issues and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first error says that you do not have permission to execute `chown` on the file `package.json`. I'm assuming `npm` is trying to change ownership of that file to do it's thing.

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chown '/misc/htdocs/hello-world/node_modules/cookie signature/package.json'
```

In short, it looks like you want to execute `npm install` with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install dependency-name
```

Or as root if you don't have `sudo`:

```
su
# type your root password at the prompt
npm install dependency-name
```

Comment: I doubt it. AFAIK root generally has full access to all files in the entire OS no matter what the file permissions are. I suggest you double check.

Comment: Only the root profile exists to begin with, I've also set the file permissions to 777 -R, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f 
sudo npm install -g n 
sudo n stable
```

Actually what it does is, it updates your `npm`.

Comment: it never occurred to you that majority still uses Windows?

Comment: Why `sudo npm install -g n; sudo n stable` instead of `sudo npm install -g npm; sudo npm stable`?

Comment: @spaffy n is a node version manager, it helps with keeping multiple node versions installed and other things; https://github.com/tj/n